# How connect to Oracle 19c with PHP pdo_oci extension

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface, oracle19c

How I can connect to Oracle 19c database with PHP pdo_oci extension on the Windows ?

I have installed Oracle Instant Client 19.0.0, PHP 7.4.4 and Apache 2.4. Oracle database is in the other server.

I get an error "TNS protocol adapter error" when I want connect with PDO.

Connection via sqlplus is successful in the command line.

Comment: We need much more detail about what you have install and how.  For example, do you have other Oracle software that may be clashing?

Comment: No. On the server is only Oracle Instant Client for connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your tnsnames.ora? If not you should create a folder inside the root of your instant client like so:

```
C:\instantclient_19_9\network\admin
```

Inside of that folder you should have a file called

```
tnsnames.ora
```

This file must contain your connection data

```
    test = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server_name_or_ip_address)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test)
    )
  )
```